# [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: javascript, react-native

Somehow I am passing a nil to a NSDictionary when I select an image from the media library or take a photo with the camera (using expo image picker)

```
     Exception '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:
      attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' was thrown while invoking 
      sendRequest on target Networking with params (
    {
    data =         {
        blob =             {
            "__collector" =                 {
            };
            blobId = "0961d8b6-cdc7-4d9b-9ef0-772c0f9141d2";
            lastModified = 1710514486398;
            offset = 0;
            size = 3735997;
            type = "";
        };
        trackingName = unknown;
    };
```

Here is the sending function with the blob in it. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

```
      const sendToBackend = async (uri) => {
    setImageLoading(true);

    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
      xhr.send(null);

    });

    const filename = new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'profileimages/' + filename);

    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, blob );
    try {
      await uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
          updateDoc(docRef, {
            image: downloadURL
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
            getUser();
            setImageLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
            setImageLoading(true);
          });
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setImageLoading(true);
    }  

    blob.close();
  };
```